# Event propagation from imported contracts

Tags: solidity, events

Im implementing a contract with imported subcontracts of my own. I'm trying to understand if I can receive the events emitted by the imported contracts, but since contracts can be inherit other ones or called all the information I'm searching for is a little bit fuzzed.

Are those events received in the main contract? Please be kind, I dont have much experience with the smart contract transactional model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You can subscribe fo events only in two ways with web3js:

1. `web3.eth.subscribe('logs', { address: 'yourContractAddress' })`
   (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html)
2. `myContract.events.allEvents or myContract.getPastEvents`
   (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events-allevents)